# YOURLS Tracking Links Through Messenger Apps

Tags: whatsapp, matomo, yourls

I am looking into the possibility to combine Piwik with YOURLS to track social link clicks on shortened URLs in Messenger Apps such as LINE Messenger, Whatsapp, etc.

Facebook seems simple and straightforward as it simply shows that it directs to (in my case) lm.facebook.com but LINE and Whatsapp do not.

YOURLS shows that there is a "visit" from the US and Japan but it does not mention any other data of the visit.

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find the URL that these messenger services use from their app, to track this link as a social referrer in Piwik?**

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 plugins I have found for YOURLS that allow it to use Matomo (formerly called Piwik, now called Matomo.

There is the 11 year old **piwik-youls**.

- But I don't think is compatible with PHP 8. It seems to cause my YOURLS to fail to display any URLs in the Admin section after updating the PHP version.
- https://github.com/interfasys/piwik-yourls

And the only 4 years old **matomo-yourls**.

- Which I haven't had a chance to play with yet.
- https://github.com/NothingTV/matomo-yourls